# How do I use "onAccountChange" to subscribe to a Solana web socket?

Tags: web3.js, react, websocket

```
const [reloadMessageList, setReloadMessageList] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchChatMessages().then(() => {});
}, [reloadMessageList]);

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");

connection.onAccountChange(
    chatPDA,
    () =>
        setReloadMessageList(!reloadMessageList),
        "confirmed"
);
```

I want to monitor for changes in "chatPDA" which is a PDA for a custom chat data account.

On change I want to alter a state "reloadMessageList", to re-fetch updated data. "reloadMessageList" is used in a "useEffect" call to perform the re-fetch.

Answer (score 1):

```
const [reloadMessageList, setReloadMessageList] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    fetchChatMessages().then(() => {});
}, [reloadMessageList]);

useEffect(()=> {
    if (activeChat) {
        const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("devnet"), "confirmed");
        connection.onAccountChange(
            chatPDA,
            (updatedAccountInfo, context) =>
            setReloadMessageList(!reloadMessageList),
            "confirmed"
        );
    }
}, [activeChat]);
```

I had to wrap the socket inside a UseEffect to make sure it was only running once on each render otherwise it was overloading the rpc with fetch requests. "activeChat".

I also had to add updatedAccountInfo and context inside of the CallBack inside onAccountChange. I do not know why that is.